# How to extract specific values from data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is similar to this small sample:

```
Tree  variable  value
 1      x1       0       
 2      x2       1
 3      x3       0
 4      x1       2
 5      x2       1
 6      x3       1
```

My question is:

How do I extract, say, just the x1 values and make it a data frame?

I'm not sure if this requires an if statement or if there's a better way in R to do this?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: as easy as doing `dataframe[dataframe$variable=="x1",]`

Answer (score 1):

Base R

```
df[df$variable == "X1",]
```

dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(variable == "x1")
```

Comment: Awesome... simple and perfect answer